# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable, but I wonder which variable is NoneType?

Tags: python, python-3.x

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
Which variable is NoneType?
Is empty list NoneType?

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        if s=="":
            return 0
        
        max = 0
        cur = 0
        l = []

        for ch in s:
            if ch not in l:
                cur += 1
                l.append(ch)
                
            else:
                if cur > max:
                    max = cur
                cur = 1
                l = [].append(ch)
        return max
```

Comment: `l = [].append(ch)` => `l = [ch]`

Comment: That works, thank you very much but why? I think [] is a list object so it has append method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Which variable is NoneType? " Well, did you try to find out? For example, by using a debugger, or by `print`ing the values of variables throughout the program? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

`l = [].append(ch)` needs to be `l = [ch]`. What you currently do is call `append` which appends an element to the list but the call itself returns nothing / `None` and *that* is assigned to `l`. During the next iteration the `in l` check fails.